# Register XMPP account using Matrix gives error 400

Tags: c#, matrix, xmpp, openfire

here is my code

```
regXmppClient.SetUsername("abcd");
        regXmppClient.SetXmppDomain("abcd.com");
        regXmppClient.Password = "abcd";
        regXmppClient.RegisterNewAccount = true;

        regXmppClient.Open();


         regXmppClient.OnRegister += new EventHandler<Matrix.EventArgs>(xmppCon_OnRegister);
regXmppClient.OnRegisterInformation += 
        new EventHandler<Matrix.Xmpp.Register.RegisterEventArgs>(xmppCon_OnRegisterInformation);
regXmppClient.OnRegisterError += new EventHandler<Matrix.Xmpp.Client.IqEventArgs>(xmppCon_OnRegisterError);
```

XMl Error log

```
 <iq type="error" id="MX_2" from="abcd.com" to="abcd.com/55ce2afc" xmlns="jabber:client">
  <query xmlns="jabber:iq:register">
    <username>abcd</username>
    <password>abcd</password>
    <email />
    <name />
    <x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="form">
      <title>XMPP Client Registration</title>
      <instructions>Please provide the following information</instructions>
      <field var="FORM_TYPE" type="hidden">
        <value>jabber:iq:register</value>
      </field>
      <field var="username" type="text-single" label="Username">
        <required />
      </field>
      <field var="name" type="text-single" label="Full name" />
      <field var="email" type="text-single" label="Email" />
      <field var="password" type="text-private" label="Password">
        <required />
      </field>
    </x>
  </query>
  <error code="400" type="modify">
    <jid-malformed xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas" />
  </error>
</iq>
```

Comment: Do you make a "get" request to the server before sending the registration form?  If so, could you include the response to that in the question?

Answer (score 0):

I got solution finally, I can Register new account using XmppClientConnection

```
        _xmppConnection.Server = SERVER_NAME;
        _xmppConnection.ConnectServer = SERVER_NAME;
        _xmppConnection.Username = objxmppData.UserName;
        _xmppConnection.Password = objxmppData.password;
        **_xmppConnection.RegisterAccount = true;**
        _xmppConnection.Open();


        _xmppConnection.OnAuthError += loginFailed;
        _xmppConnection.OnLogin += new ObjectHandler(xmpp_OnLogin);
```

As in above code make RegisterAccount = true will do both create new account and loggedin with the same.

Answer (score 0):

you code submits a xdata from and the old jabber style fields , ,  and . Some servers have problems with that, and I guess they are right.

If you want to use old jabber style registration then remove the xdata from in your set query. If you want to use xdata then remove the old jabber style fields.

see also: http://forum.ag-software.net/thread/874-How-to-Register-a-new-Account-on-an-xmpp-server

Comment: thanks for suggestions, but can you please explain what do you mean by old jabber style fields ? i got it working with solution provided in above answer and its working also so is that ok ?

Comment: follow the link I added. It is described in detail there.